# Using rxdart to Debounce Geolocator Updates for Real-Time Driver Location in Flutter App updates drivers data only once

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, throttling, google-geolocation

I'm developing an app with car drivers. When the driver is marked as active, it is shown as active in Firebase, and their position is constantly updated. However, I realized that it's not necessary to update the driver's position every second; updating every five or seven seconds would be sufficient. So, I looked for a way to delay the events generated by getPositionStream() from Geolocator by 5 seconds between each call. I found that I could use a package called "rxdart," so I implemented it. However, now the driver's location isn't updating at all.

```
streamSubscriptionPosition = debouncedStream.listen((Position position) {
    driverCurrentPosition = position;

    if (isDriverActive == true) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "ssss");
      Geofire.setLocation(
        currentFirebaseUser!.uid,
        driverCurrentPosition!.latitude,
        driverCurrentPosition!.longitude,
      );

      if (driverIsInRange(
          driverCurrentPosition!.latitude, driverCurrentPosition!.longitude)) {
        driverIsInQueueArea = true;
        addDriverToQueue();
      } else if (driverIsInQueueArea == true) {
        AssistantMethods.removeDriverFromQueue(
          context,
          "You're out of range, so you've been removed from the driver queue. You will now receive trips based on geographic proximity.",
        );
        driverIsInQueueArea = false;
      }
    }

    LatLng latLng = LatLng(
      driverCurrentPosition!.latitude,
      driverCurrentPosition!.longitude,
    );

    newGoogleMapController!.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(latLng));
  });
}
```

I tried using debouncedStream, but it's not working as expecte, but before I tried to use the method "throttleDuration" but it didn't get recognized as a function, I'm correctly importing the package rxdart

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/ThrottleExtensions.html